# how to make one class constructor Partial

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Sorry if the title is not too specific, I don't know the name of what I am trying to do.

I have a class

```
type Cvalues {
    d: any;
    e: any;
    f: any;
 }

class Character {
    a: any;
    b: any;
    c: Cvalues
}
```

and I want the constructor to receive all its properties possibly, but I want C to be a Partial without casting C as `C: Partial<CValues>`.

my "solution" that is not working:

```
type CharacterConstructor = {
    [K in keyof Character]? Character[K]
} & {
    C?: Partial<Cvalues >
}
```

I want the Character to be built like:

```
new Character({
    a: 1,
    c: {
        e: 2
    }
)
```

OR

```
new Character(
    b: 3,
)
```

I tryed several configurations for the Constructor of the class, and I want a type to fit my needs, but cant find it or a close solution

Comment: What value should `Character.c` be assigned to if it's not passed in the constructor?

Comment: I have a function with the defaults values, that's why you can pass it or not in the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parameter type you're looking for (written out the long way!) is:

```js
type CharacterParams = {
    a?: any;
    b?: any;
    c?: {
        d?: any;
        e?: any;
        f?: any;
    }
}
```

then it seems like you're most of the way there. You can use `Partial<..>` and `Omit<..>`:

```js
type Cvalues = {
    d: any;
    e: any;
    f: any;
 }

type CharacterValues = {
    a: any;
    b: any;
    c: Cvalues;
}

class Character {
    constructor(
       { a, b, c }:
         Partial<
           Omit<CharacterValues, "c">   // Replace .c ...
             & { c: Partial<Cvalues> }  // ... with any subset of .c
         >
    ) { /* constructor stuff */ }
}
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgbgQwDYFcIGcoF4oG8BQURUAJgFxQIB2IA3IcRBdXQ0QGbM31QC+++UJFgALBACcEAY2ARxANWRpMOAsUpdW6gEaaexKRXhKM9fvilIE6TDDGSZcvAPVSA9lXTBxKGW-EAFLiUADRQ2mFSfBQAChLAAJbIADwA8gC2CcDJdhLSsgom6GEARFIlAHxQAGR4UIZQceKJKcaoGFW8FQCUbM7q-OZUEADuonmOgcG6UADMfN206ssrAPSrUG4A1ggg+MNjuQ4FQRpQAIyRFMFMUABMfAtLUOubOyBAA)